# Days of the Week are being displayed backwords (Sat, fri, thru, wed, etc) and I can't figure out why

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, linq-to-entities

In my project I am filling a complex `ViewModel` with data via `LINQ to Entities` then using that data to build a table that will display a daily timesheet for a user. I appear to be grabbing the data right since when I print the amount of hours worked that day they are correct but the problem is the Date printed is wrong, they are being displayed backwards.

[image]

Here is the model:

```
public class TimesheetWeeklyTableVM
{
    public int TimesheetHeaderID { get; set; }
    public DateTime WeekEndingDate { get; set; }
    public decimal TotalWeekHours { get; set; }

    public List<TimesheetDailyVM> DaysOfWeek { get; set; }

    public TimesheetWeeklyTableVM()
    {
        DaysOfWeek = new List<TimesheetDailyVM>();

        foreach (DayOfWeek dayOfWeek in Enum.GetValues(typeof(DayOfWeek)))
        {
            DaysOfWeek.Add(new TimesheetDailyVM()
            {
                DayOfWeek = dayOfWeek
            });
        }
    }
}

public class TimesheetDailyVM
{
    public DayOfWeek DayOfWeek { get; set; }

    public double TotalHours
    {
        get
        {
            return TimeSpan.FromSeconds(Tasks.Sum(p => (p.EndDateTime - p.StartDateTime).TotalSeconds)).TotalHours;
        }
    }

    public IEnumerable<TimesheetDailyHoursVM> Tasks { get; set; }

    public TimesheetDailyVM()
    {
        Tasks = new List<TimesheetDailyHoursVM>();
    }
}

public class TimesheetDailyHoursVM
{
    public int TimesheetID { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartDateTime { get; set; }
    public DateTime EndDateTime { get; set; }
    public string ProjectCode { get; set; }
    public string ProjectDescription { get; set; }
    public string TaskCode { get; set; }
    public string TaskDescription { get; set; }
}
```

and the code used to fill that model:

```
var weekEndingDate = TimesheetHelper.GetWeekEndingDate(date);
var employeeID = UserHelper.GetUserID(User.Identity.Name);

using (var db = new JobSightDbContext())
{
    var model = db.TimesheetHeaders
                    .Where(timesheetHeader => timesheetHeader.WeekEndingDate == weekEndingDate && timesheetHeader.EmployeeID == employeeID)
                    .Select(timesheetHeader => new TimesheetWeeklyTableVM()
                    {
                        WeekEndingDate = weekEndingDate,
                        TimesheetHeaderID = timesheetHeader.ID,
                        TotalWeekHours = timesheetHeader.TotalHours
                    }).FirstOrDefault();

    var headerID = model.TimesheetHeaderID;

    var timeRecords = db.Timesheets
                        .Where(timesheet => timesheet.TimesheetHeaderID == headerID)
                        .ToList()
                        .GroupBy(timesheet => timesheet.StartDateTime.DayOfWeek);

    foreach (var record in timeRecords)
    {
        model.DaysOfWeek[(int)record.Key].Tasks = record.Select(x => new TimesheetDailyHoursVM()
        {
            TimesheetID = x.ID,
            StartDateTime = x.StartDateTime,
            EndDateTime = x.EndDateTime,
            ProjectCode = x.ProjectCode,
            TaskCode = x.TaskCode
        });
    }

    return PartialView(model);
}
```

and the code to display it:

```
@model TimesheetWeeklyTableVM

<table border="1">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                Total Hours: <br />
                @Model.TotalWeekHours
            </th>
            @foreach (var day in Model.DaysOfWeek)
            {
                <th>
                    @Model.WeekEndingDate.AddDays(-(int)day.DayOfWeek).ToString("ddd MM/dd/yy")
                    <br />@day.TotalHours Hours Worked
                </th>
            }
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I tried adding an `.OrderBy(timesheet => timesheet.StartDateTime.DayOfWeek);` to the `LINQ` query that filles `timeRecords` but that did not affect anything. What am I missing so the table will display the days in `Sun, Mon, Tue, Wed, Thr, Fri, Sat`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your

```
@Model.WeekEndingDate.AddDays(-(int)day.DayOfWeek).ToString("ddd MM/dd/yy")
```

line of code in the view. You have a collection whose `DayOfWeek` property ranges from `0` (Sunday) to `6` (Saturday) and assuming `WeekEndingDate` is 14th May (the last day of this week), then the 1st iteration transalates to

```
 WeekEndingDate.AddDays(-0) // results in 14th May
```

and the second iteration translates to

```
WeekEndingDate.AddDays(-1) // results in 13th May
```

etc. You need to change the view code to

```
WeekEndingDate.AddDays(((int)day.DayOfWeek) - 6).ToString("ddd MM/dd/yy");
```

so that the 1st iteration translates to

```
WeekEndingDate.AddDays(-6) // results in 8th May
```

so that the 2nd iteration translates to

```
WeekEndingDate.AddDays(-5) // results in 9th May
```

As a side note: I would consider adding a parameter to your `TimesheetWeeklyTableVM` constructor

```
public TimesheetWeeklyTableVM(DateTime weekEnding)
{
    DaysOfWeek = new List<TimesheetDailyVM>();
    DateTime startDate = weekEnding.AddDays(-6);
    for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    {
        DaysOfWeek.Add(new TimesheetDailyVM()
        {
            Date = startDate.AddDays(i)
        };
    }
}
```

and in your `TimesheetDailyVM` model, replace `public DayOfWeek DayOfWeek { get; set; }` with

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:ddd MM/dd/yy}")]
public DateTime Date{ get; set; }
```

and in the your first query, use

```
.Select(timesheetHeader => new TimesheetWeeklyTableVM(weekEndingDate)
```

and in the view, you can then use

```
@foreach (var day in Model.DaysOfWeek)
{
    <th>
       @Html.DisplayFor(m => day.Date)
       <br />@day.TotalHours Hours Worked
    </th>
}
```

You could also add a `DisplayFormat` attribute for the hours

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:0} HoursWorked")] // adjust if you want decimal places
public double TotalHours
{
   .....
```

and use `@Html.DisplayFor(m => day.TotalHours)` in the view

Comment: Thanks for this. I was working with vendettamit this afternoon before I had to leave for a doc appointment and the end of the work day and we just figured out the problems was with that line of code. I was going to continue working on it in the morning so I will give your suggestion a shot to see how it goes when I get back in tomorrow.

Comment: Note that I just edited the answer with a suggestion to simplify you view a bit.

Comment: Thanks, I welcome any and all suggestions on making things easier and more efficient. But I see in your edit your using a parametrized contractor in the `SELECT`. LINQ to Entities does not allow that.

Comment: Assume you mean `Linq to SQL` (works fine with Linq to Entities)

Comment: Maybe, I had tried that once and it was giving me an error about the constructor and I could have swarn it was `LINQ to Entites` but maybe I have been using `LINQ to SQL` all this time. Not 100% sure, I will give it another shot

Comment: It would certainly work if you were to use `var data = db.TimesheetHeaders.Where(...).FirstOrDefault(); var model = new TimesheetWeeklyTableVM(weekEndingDate) { TimesheetHeaderID = data.ID, TotalWeekHours = data.TotalHours };`

Comment: So I just got done testing all this and everything is working as I need it. The basic fix of changing the view was all that was needed but I also updated the code as you recommended for the `ViewMode` and it's supporting code with no problems. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what order your DaysOfWeek collection is ordered. Based on the `high to low` or `low to high` value the day will be printed.

```
@Model.WeekEndingDate.AddDays(-(int)day.DayOfWeek).ToString("ddd MM/dd/yy")
```

According to current output it looks like your DaysOfWeek list is ordered in Ascending order. Change it to descending order you'll get the desired result.

```
 @foreach (var day in Model.DaysOfWeek.Cast<int>().OrderByDescending(x => x))
```

**update -**
The design of your entities is not aligned correctly. To fix the syncing issue, don't initialize the DaysOfWeek list in `TimesheetWeeklyTableVM` constructor. DayOfWeek can be fetched from `TimesheetDailyHoursVM` class property StartDateTime. Simply `StartDateTime.DayOfWeek` will give you the day of week.
 Assuming that your StartDateTime and EndDateTime are covering a single day. The property `DayOfWeek` of `TimesheetDailyVM` can be initialized like:

```
public DayOfWeek DayOfWeek 
{ 
 get {  
       return Tasks.First().StartDateTime.DayOfWeek; 
     }
 }
```

Comment: How? As stated I added a `OrderByDescending` to the `timeRecords` query but that did not change anything.

Comment: Thanks, did not know I could attach a `LINQ` command there. That makes the days display in the right order but now it shows my query is pulling the hours for the wrong dates :(

Comment: You should order the daysOfWeek when you're initializing the data in sync with hours in the controller itself. No need to sort the days in views once you do that and this should fix it.

Comment: That was what I was originally trying to do but can not figure out how.

Comment: Ok, I think I followed your update. I commented out the entire `public TimesheetWeeklyTableVM()` block and converted the `public DayofWeek Dayof Week {get;set;}` block to yours but now I get the error "Cannot implicitily convert type System.DateTime to bool" on `t.StartDateTime`

Comment: My bad the syntax was incorrect for `First()`. I have updated the code try now.

Comment: The code compiles but I can't verify if it works as the loop for filling `DayOfWeek` is now broke. Will have to try and figure that one out next as I am sure your code will work.

Comment: Try to order the complete list now based on the dayOfWeek. May this should work `foreach(var day in DaysOfWeek.OrderByDescending(x => (int)x.DayOfWeek))`

Comment: I can't get that far. Because the `DaysOfWeek = new List<TimesheetDailyVM>();` was taken out of the VM the `foreach (var record in timeRecords)` is now broken.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111677/discussion-between-vendettamit-and-matthew).

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you just need to order your `DaysOfWeek` You could probably do it in your view `Model.DaysOfWeek` or after you've interated on it here `foreach (DayOfWeek dayOfWeek in Enum.GetValues(typeof(DayOfWeek)))`